# When is new State where available in Component available

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assuming I have a function (`_onClick()`) which is called on every click, which calls another function `_doSomethingWithCount()`. However, after calling `_doSomethingWithCount()` I set the state. In this case, I increase the `counter` by `1`.

```
const Foo = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    const _onClick = () => {
        _doSomethingWithCount();
        setCounter(counter + 1);
    }
    
    const doSomethingWithCount = () => {
        console.log(counter)
    }
        

    return (
        <button onClick={() => _onClick()}>Click Me</button>
    )
}
```

Will the `console.log()` in `doSomethingWithCount()` *always* log the value of count before I called `setCounter(counter + 1);` thus the "old" value? Or will `doSomethingWithCount()` wait until the `state` is set because it relies on a variable from the state? Or is there some sort of "race" going on. If the `state` is set faster than JS can execute `doSomethingWithCount()`, `doSomethingWithCount()` will sometimes have the update `count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your code does not match your text

You say,

> However, before calling _doSomethingWithCount() I set the state. In
> this case, I increase the counter by 1.

But your code says,

```
    _doSomethingWithCount();
    setCounter(counter + 1);
```

#### If you do what your text says...

then `counter` will have its new value when `_doSomethingWithCount` runs.

#### If you do what your code says...

then `counter` will have its old value when `_doSomethingWithCount` runs.

#### Either way, there is no race.

At the point in the code where you call `_doSomethingWithCount`, that function will run, and the value of `counter` at that time will be determined by whether the `setCounter()` is above or below the function call, in your code.

Comment: Hupsala, sorry. I edit my Q.